# WKHTMLTOPDF PDF could not be generated

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wkhtmltopdf, rbenv, gemfile

My rails app is working fine in many aspects but when I try to generate pdf on a production server, I get this error below. On my local computer, it's working fine. How can I go about this?.

````
 Command Error: /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/2.7.0/bundler/definition.rb:495:in `validate_ruby!': Your Ruby version is 2.7.0, but your Gemfile specified 2.7.2 (Bundler::RubyVersionMismatch)
    from /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/2.7.0/bundler/definition.rb:470:in `validate_runtime!'
    from /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/2.7.0/bundler.rb:143:in `setup'
    from /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/2.7.0/bundler/setup.rb:20:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/2.7.0/bundler/ui/shell.rb:136:in `with_level'
    from /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/2.7.0/bundler/ui/shell.rb:88:in `silence'
    from /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/2.7.0/bundler/setup.rb:20:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:92:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:92:in `require'```
Note that am using ruby 2.7.2 and I dont have ruby 2.7.0
````

Comment: Are you suing ruby 2.7.2 in production as well?

Comment: Yes here is the result of ruby -v  >> ruby 2.7.2p137 (2020-10-01 revision 5445e04352) [x86_64-linux]

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete "bundle" folder in your app root (on production server), and run "bundle" or "bundle install" afterwards. Solved this issue for me some time ago.